# How to calculate expected code length?

Tags: binary

[image]

[image]

How to calculate expected code length?

Comment: This question belongs to Math or even better Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange.

Comment: The calculation is done for you, right before your eyes. Which part don't you understand?

Comment: I don't understand how there are two times 0.25 and 0.2

Comment: The five 2-length codewords have probabilities 0.25, 0.25 and 0.2. The two 3-length codewords each have probability 0.15, all given in the table at the top. The contribution of each codeword to the expected length is length*probability, so the total expected length is the sum of all these expectations. The terms have been grouped in a straightforward way, which unfortunately makes the sum slightly less obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Should be:
$$L = \sum p_i l_i = (0.25 + 0.25 + 0.2) \times 2 + (0.15 + 0.15) \times 3 = 2.3 $$